# Print a stock price if it changes by a certain percentage after scraping it off yahoo

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Currently I only have the code together to scrape the real time stock price off of yahoo finance. Any help or resources would be appreciated. Here's what I have now:

```py
import bs4
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parsePrice():

    r=requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTX?p=RTX')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    price = soup.find('div', class_ = "My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)").find('span').text

    return price

while True:
    print("The current stock price is " + str(parsePrice()))
```

Comment: Well - can you think of an approach to the problem? How do *you* know, when you look at the page yourself, whether the stock price has changed by that much? When you say "change" - *compared to what*? another value on the same webpage? or compared to a previous time that you checked the page? or what?

Answer (score 0):

I would put all of that code in a while true so that you get the new html every single iteration of the for loop. You also will want to implement a time.sleep(some_number_of_seconds) (import time) so your ip does not get banned.

Edit: 
Oops I forgot about the only printing if it changes enough part. So what you could do is set price to an integer in the loop.
So like:

```
old_price = 1.0 # or your desired float
while True:
   r=requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTX?p=RTX')
     price = soup.find('div', class_ = "My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)").find('span').text
     if price/old_price>1.05 or price/old_price<1.05:# This would do at least five percent change
        print(price)
        old_price = price
     time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You can’t divide by zero

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense.

Comment: If you think this is the right answer can you please say that i am working towards 50 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that looks for greater than a 20 percent change (negative or positive) in price and prints it out.

```
import bs4
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def parsePrice():

    r=requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/RTX?p=RTX')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    price = soup.find('div', class_ = "My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)").find('span').text

    return price

def get_change(current, previous):
    if current == previous:
        return 0
    try:
        return (abs(current - previous) / previous) * 100.0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

old_price = 0
percent = 20
while True:
    current_price = float(parsePrice())
    if get_change(current_price, old_price) > percent:
        print(f"There was a change greater than {percent}%. The stock price was ${old_price}, and the current price is now ${current_price}")
    old_price = current_price
```

I can introduce `time.sleep(time_in_seconds)` from the library `time` to create larger intervals that may produce the percent change you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Applied both approaches and learned a lot.